# Returning the file name extension in java

Tags: java

I have a parameter which contains the following value

```
 String filesTypesallowed =".xsl,.xslx ";
```

Now i have pass this parameter in another method named filterfile as shown below now as you can see that in the method i am getting the fileName as one of the parameter in which i must be getting any file name lets say it mite be abc.csv file , so what i have to do is that check whether the file that i am getting inside the parameter fileName ends with extension .xlsx or .xls then in that case i have to return the file name but other than that extension lets say i have got a file with an extension like ert.csv then in that case i have to return simply null

please advise how to achieve this what i have tried is

```
private String filterfile(String fileName , String filesTypesallowed) {
String s ; 
s =fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));



}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to return a string, or a boolean?  If a string, what is that string supposed to contain?

Comment: @NathanMerrillbwell i was trying to return a string that contains the entire file name which was paassed to me in the fileName parameter only if it is .xsl or .xslx only other wise null

Comment: If you use Java 7 or higher you could use the method String.endsWith(String). Also if you just want to select which file is acceptable maybe a [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) would be something for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the `filesTypesallowed` and then check if the extension is any of them:

```
private String filterfile(String fileName , String filesTypesallowed) {
    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    String[] allowedExtensions = filesTypesallowed.split(",");
    if (Arrays.asList(allowedExtensions).contains(extension)) {
        return fileName;
    } 
    return null;    
}
```

Comment: `filesTypesAllowed` ends with a space in the example.

Comment: Isn't creating a list of the extensions vs iterating over the extensions a bit inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the array, then build a `Stream` off it and simply use `anyMatch`.

Example :

```
private String filterFile(final String fileName, final String fileTypesAllowed) {
    return Stream.of(fileTypesAllowed.trim().split(","))
                 .anyMatch(ext -> ext.equals(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")))) 
                     ? fileName 
                     : null;
}
```

Note that I made a call to `String.trim` as the example you gave us contains one whitespace at the end, I'm not sure if it was a typo or not... Remove it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two key parts to this problem, getting the file extensions, and checking if the string ends with any of those extensions.

To get the file extensions, you need to use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).  If we pass it a comma, it'll return an array of the parts separated by a comma:

```
String[] extensions = fileTypesAllowed.split(",");
```

To check to see if the string ends with the extensions, we need to loop through the extensions, and use [String.endsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) to check to see if it ends with the extension:

```
for (String extension: extensions){
    if (fileName.endsWith(extension){
        return fileName;
    }
}
//If we get here, then it doesn't end with any of the extensions
return null;
```

As a side note, your `fileTypesAllowed` variable contains a space at the end.  You can remove it using [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()), but the *ideal* way to do it is to pass an array of strings into the function in the first place.  Passing lists as a string really isn't the way to do things.